# Java Given this source code how can it be put into a .jar and attached to my project as an external library

Tags: java, jar

I am using the Java Marine API found here: https://github.com/ktuukkan/marine-api but the jar they provide on their download page is not suitable for my project as it misses the the ability to read one of the sentence types i am using (the task involves GPS Sentences from a receiver).

The question i have is, i have cloned the Java code from this github repository how i will now edit this, it has a build.xml so how can i convert this code into a .jar so i can attach it to my project as an external library.

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Get the source code of the Marine API then it will be easy to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has also `pom.xml` present in the root directory. It means it uses Maven tool for building. You should find the jar file in the resulting `target` directory after running

`mvn install`

For skipping the test suite you can run

`mvn -DskipTests install`

However, according to javadocs this library allows you to add your own parsers at runtime too, so you don't actually need to build it.